# How can I group many animations under a single name?

Tags: animation, groups

I'm quite new into animating in Blender, so I'm currently very confused about how to do simple things. I need to program something in Javascript and I have to animate a car being roofless. The thing is that that animation has many independent parts moving separately and I need an easy way to name them under one denomination for me to be able to refer to every single one of theme as a single one.

I firstly thought about grouping them all together but I have no idea If this is possible and I don't know where to start.

Comment: that's what the NLA is useful for. Maybe watch some tutorials about NLA.

Comment: I've been looking for a way to group them all together but I don't find any solution. Can you get me closer to what I trying to do using the NLA please?

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.5. Older versions like 3.3 doesn't allow this (for actions/animations), not sure if 3.4.

Select "Blender File" in the outliner.

Then select your actions(animations).

Then Control + F2 to rename them.

Switch to "ALL" (it looks there's a bug, it doesn't work if you choose "SELECTED")

Select "Action Clips" as type of data to rename.

Type -> Set name

Method -> New

Name-> "Name you want"

[image]

Comment: Thanks Miguel, really helpful from your part. I've tried it and it kinda works. When I write down the animation name that all actions are supposed to have in Javascript it just reproduces one tho, dont know why. But you got me a little bit closer. Thank you!